# ANSI Key Sequences

Tags: c, linux, ansi-escape

- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 x86 (Debian Wheezy)
- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

I am writing a function that reads ANSI escape sequences generated by keys and returns a macro corresponding to the key entered. I have tested my function and it reads the arrow keys properly. But the function can only read arrow keys currently and I want to add the control/alternate combinations, function keys, home, insert, etc. However I cannot seem to find a list of all the ANSI escape sequences for keys. In fact I found a copy of ECMA-48 and was confused when there was no mention of escape sequences for keys. So does anyone know where I can get a list of the ANSI escape sequences that correspond to the function keys, arrow keys, etc.?

Comment: termcap // terminfo: GIYF.

Comment: @wildplasser are you saying that termcap and terminfo have the information I am look for or are you saying I should use termcap and terminfo?

Comment: GIYF, baby! Its hard, but you'l get by...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that arrow keys are brought up *somewhere* in ECMA048, but frankly I always found that document pretty much impenetrable. So, instead, I'll direct you to the `ctlseqs.txt` document from the XTerm source code:

http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.txt

This document focuses more on the control sequences used to control output, but does describe input control sequences in some detail as well. Search for the heading `Alt and Meta Keys` for the start of the relevant section.

Comment: The [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) Wikipedia page is also quite useful. It even includes a link to the [HTML version](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) or ctlseqs.txt.